# Azure granting VM identity

Tags: azure, identity

I am new to Azure and trying to grant VM permission to access azure resource by following an [Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/msi-tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm) and so far have successfully finished:

1. Created the identity
2. Assigned the identity to VM
3. Granted reader role to the identity

Now I am trying to get an access token to read resource via running the following command in the VM from **#2** (replacing *UAMI CLIENT ID* with what I got from **#1** above) :

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com/&client_id=<UAMI CLIENT ID>"
```

This command returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

I dont't understand what this "404" means, can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the steps in the document are all right. The suggestion is that check the steps you had done and try it again. You can get more details in [How to use managed identities for Azure resources on an Azure VM to acquire an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token). You can see the 404 error in the [Error Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#error-handling). Azure also advise to try it again:

> It is recommended to retry if you receive a 404, 429, or 5xx error
>   code.

And as you showed the error message, I think maybe it is not the result of the correct server return. You should check if there is another VM use the address.

Comment: In case you still get error, retry the whole process